# Android Webview takes 30 seconds to load

Tags: java, android, webview

We are using webviews on an Android app. The login activity is native and after logging in the user goes to a menu activity with a webview. Every menu option leads the user to different activities, each of them with its own webview. All these activities - including the menu - extend from the same BaseWebViewActivity class.

It all worked well until quite recently (one year ago, perhaps) when the app started to take 30 seconds to load the webview. I have added some metrics on WebViewClient and it is always 30 seconds.

The HTML code does not have remote dependencies (all necessary scripts are bundled within the APK) and it does not make any AJAX request.

If I remove everything from the HTML and write "Hello world", then it is loaded instantaneously. If I leave any sort of HTML tag (except for , ,  or ) in the file, then it takes 30 seconds to load.

Things I have tried:

- Turning hardware acceleration on/off
- Removing everything from the HTML
- Make webview not debuggable
- Removed the WebViewClient
- Requested google.com instead of the local file
- Removed almost everything from the HTML file (see above)
- Uninstalled Android System WebView updates
- Updated Android System WebView (neither of these worked)
- Turned cookie management on/off

This loading time is oddly specific and I'm thinking this is somehow a timeout of something. However, Network Inspector confirmed that no network requests are taking place at the time. Also, during these 30 seconds, the UI and logcat become completely blocked and will only resume the operations have the 30 seconds have elapsed.

Thanks in advance!

```
/**** Option Activity ****/
public class OptionActivity extends SPBaseWebActivity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_calendar);

    this.webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    DebugManager.log("Entered calendar activity");

    DebugManager.clearPerformanceCheckpoints("calendar_view");
    DebugManager.addPerformanceCheckpoint("calendar_view", "onCreate finished");
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    DebugManager.addPerformanceCheckpoint("calendar_view", "onResume start");

    String url = "calendar.html";
    setupWebview(url);
    reloadOnResume = false;

    DebugManager.addPerformanceCheckpoint("calendar_view", "onResume finished - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
}

@Override
protected void onPageLoaded(WebView view, String url)
{
    super.onPageLoaded(view, url);

    DebugManager.addPerformanceCheckpoint("calendar_view", "onPageLoaded finished - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
}
}


/**** SPBaseWebActivity ****/
public class SPBaseWebActivity implements WebAppInterfaceDelegate
{
protected WebView webview = null;
protected WebAppInterface jsInterface = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    if (this.webview == null)
        this.webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    setupWebview(null);
}

protected void setupWebview(String url)
{
    if (this.webview != null)
    {
        if (url == null || url.length() == 0)
            url = "base/empty.html";
        else if (!url.contains("http"))
            url = "app/" + url;

        MVWebChromeClient mvwcc = new MVWebChromeClient();
        mvwcc.parentActivity = this;

        this.webview.setWebChromeClient(mvwcc);

        DebugManager.addPerformanceCheckpoint("webview_loading", "Webview client init - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));

        this.webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                DebugManager.addPerformanceCheckpoint("webview_loading", "onPageStarted - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
                {
                    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(view, true);
                    CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
                }
                else
                    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

                DebugManager.addPerformanceCheckpoint("webview_loading", "onPageLoaded - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
                onPageLoaded(view, url);
            }
        });

        DebugManager.addPerformanceCheckpoint("webview_loading", "Webview client created - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(Globals.DEBUG);
        }

        if (!url.contains("http"))
            this.webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pages/" + url);
        else
            this.webview.loadUrl(url);

        this.webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        this.webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        this.webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        this.jsInterface = new WebAppInterface(this);
        this.jsInterface.delegate = this;
        this.jsInterface.parentActivity = this;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(this.webview, true);
            CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
        }
        else
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

        this.webview.addJavascriptInterface(this.jsInterface, "Android");
        this.webview.requestFocus();
    }
}
}


/**** HTML file ****/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>MV Reports - Agendamento</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../mv/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../mv/addons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../mv/addons/material2/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    Takes 30 to load
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you run the profiler to see what functions its taking time in?  This sounds like something is running on the main thread the entire time

Comment: I ran both the app inspector and the profiler (CPU, Memory, Energy). CPU is steady at zero, memory is steady at around 250MB but energy consumption goes double. I can't understand why. I stopped the execution mid-30 seconds and couldn't find any clue to what is going on.

Comment: If you ran the profiler, it should show you what functions it spent the most time in, and you can go from there.

Comment: While it might not directly address your query, I recommend attempting to load the webview concurrently with the user's login. This can be achieved by utilizing a ViewSwitcher within a single activity, where both the login layout and webview are present inside a ViewSwitcher. This approach eliminates the need for a separate activity. As a result, the webview can finish loading while the user is entering their username, password, and initiating the login process.

Comment: @GabeSechan From your comment I understand that I may be using the profiler wrong (or the wrong profiler). This is all I can see (image below), I can't see the functions being called. Am I on the wrong place?

https://imagebin.ca/v/7WOi5FbsWvV8

Comment: @SHAHEENBSV Thank you, that would be a great idea. But sadly I can't do that, since the information of the webview directly depends upon the user authentication.

Comment: @Sagito https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/record-traces  You can record a trace, which will use sampling techniques to break down what threads are running, what functions they're running in, and the time spent in each.  It's an incredibly useful tool for performance issues on the CPU

Comment: @GabeSechan this is incredible, thank you so much! I didn't know about this tool.